# Paging dynamic query results

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Paging using LINQ can be easily done using the `Skip()` and `Take()` extensions. 
I have been scratching my head for quite some time now, trying to find a good way to perform paging of a dynamic collection of entities - i.e. a collection that can change between two sequential queries.

Assume a `query` that without paging will return 20 objects of type `MyEntity`.
The following two lines will trigger two DB hits that will populate `results1` and `results2` with all of the objects in the dataset.

```
List<MyEntity> results1 = query.Take(10).ToList();
List<MyEntity> results2 = query.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

Now let's assume the data is dynamic, and that a new `MyEntity` is inserted into the DB between the two queries, in such a way that the original query will place the new entity in the **first** page.
In that case, `results2` list will contain an entity that also exists in `results1`,
causing duplication of results being sent to the consumer of the query.

Assuming a record from the **first page** was **deleted**, it will result missing a record that should have originally appear on `results2`.

I thought about adding a `Where()` clause to the query that verify that the records where not retrieved on a previous page, but it seems like the wrong way to go, and it won't help with the second scenario.

I thought about keeping a record of query executions' timestamps, attaching a `LastUpdatedTimestamp` to each entity and filtering entities that were changed after the previous page request. That direction will fail on the third page afterwards...

How is this normally done? 
Is there a way to run a query against an old snapshot of the DB?

**Edit:**
The background is an Asp.NET MVC WebApi service that responds to a simple GET request to retrieve the list of entities. The client retrieves a page of entities, and presents them to the user. When scrolled down, the client sends another request to the service, to retrieve another page of entities, which should be added to the first page which is already presented to the user.

Comment: What's the nature of the how the data being consumed/displayed? And how does the user use the paging feature you're talking about? I think some more context would help in coming up with solutions that make sense given your use cases.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit, if there is anything else I can add, please let me know

Comment: Sorry to revive old posts, but do you managed to resolve this? And if so, do you recall how?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to keep a TimeStamp of the first query and exclude any results that have been added after that time. However this solution puts the data into a "stale" state, i.e the data is fixed at a certain point in time, which is usually a bad idea unless you have a very good reason to do it.

Another way of doing this (again depending on your application) would be to store the list of all objects in memory and then only display a certain number of results at one time.

```
List<Entity> _list;
public class SomeCtor()
{
    _list = _db.Entities.ToList();
}
public List<Entity> GetFirst10
{
    get
    {
        return _list.Take(10);
    }
}
public List<Entity> GetSecond10
{
    get
    {
        return _list.Skip(10).Take(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am afraid that both of the options you presented will make my WebApi service STATE-FULL, which I believe is not proper implementation in a web server

Comment: Your desired functionality is Stateful, which as I pointed out is a bad idea. Generally you just wouldn't implement this if you want to remain stateless